# Azure ML Workspace missing secrets of associated keyvault, no way to access its datastores

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

by mistake I deleted the secrets from my keyvault, which were associated to my default Azure Machine Learning datastores (workspacefilestore, workspaceartifactstore and workspaceblobstore).
As a result, when I click on one of these datastores (or a dataset depending on them), I get the error "**Please make sure that you are passing valid secret names and that the keyvault https://mauromikv00.v.**", where mauromikv00 (without ".v.") is my associated keyvault.
[image]
I tried to recover the deleted secrets, but they aren't in the recycle bin anymore.

If I were able to click on the datastore, I would be able to use the "updated authentication" button to re-associate the blob storage to the keyvault. But the error above happens as soon as I click on the datastore, preventing me from updating its authentication credentials.

Answer (score 1):

There is a case, that we can follow to recover even though when soft deletion happened. But for that, there is a case to know that ***"secrets/recover permission"***  is enabled or not. If this permission is enabled, there is high chance of recovery of the deleted secret by following the steps mentioned in:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/recover-deleted-secret/recover-deleted-secret

```
POST {vaultBaseUrl}/deletedsecrets/{secret-name}/recover?api-version=7.3
```

Comment: Thanks! I recovered many secrets that were in the recycle bin, however the workspace still cannot access the datastores I mentioned. Don't we have a direct way to re-generate the binding between AzureML and its default storage so that the new secrets are created?

Comment: We will not having direct method to re-generate the binding. We need to start from the initial position.

Comment: I see. But what is the way to restart from scratch? At the moment I cannot even remove the datastores